# Crontab will not run?

Tags: python, cron

My cron tab is set up like this:

```
 * * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/amazon/hello.py
```

hello.py is

```
      #!/usr/bin/python
      print "yo"
```

I am trying to just run the script and get it working to print to the console yo every minute?  What am I doing wrong I included the header to where python is on my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron program redirects the standard output and so you don't see the program's output. But it sends the output as mail to the system. Try running the `mail` program to verify.

If you want to write the output to a specific file, use:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/amazon/hello.py > /home/user/test.txt
```

If you want to *cheat* try using the `tty` command to find the terminal file and use this file to redirect your output

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
```

and then:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /root/amazon/hello.py > /dev/pts/0
```

but this will only work as long you are connected to this terminal.

Comment: Hmmm, using the top one, it generates a file test.txt.  However "yo" is not being printed from the script to the text file so it is not being called.  What do you think the problem is?

Comment: Is it the same program? Try running the program at the command line to see if it's running. Then try seeing the contents of the test.txt.

Comment: Hmmm the script does not seem to be working at all, what could be a cause of this?

Comment: Yes fix the script first

Comment: Ok Script is fixed however when I do: 40 14 * * * /usr/bin/python /root/amazon/master.py > /dev/pts/1 it will not run at 2:40.  However if I do every minute it does run? Is my timer off?